# Map Network Drive PowerShell and Name it

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

Using the following script I can map network drives but can't rename them, I have used this bit of code before, but there was a really easy way to rename it to an easily identifiable name instead of the network path.

```
$net = new-object -ComObject WScript.Network

$net.MapNetworkDrive("N:", "\\172.18.165.2\Staff_Users$\\*USERNAME*\My Documents", $false, "*USERNAME*", "*PASSWORD*")
$net.MapNetworkDrive("R:", "\\172.18.165.2\Resource$", $false, "*USERNAME*", "*PASSWORD*")
$net.MapNetworkDrive("S:", "SIMS", "\\172.18.165.3\SIMS", $false, "*USERNAME*", "*PASSWORD*")
```

Hope you guys can help!

Thanks in advance!

M

Answer (score 2):

In Version 3 you can use the [Remove-PSDrive](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849760.aspx) and [New-PSDrive](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849829.aspx) cmdlet instead of net use or the WScript.Network comobject. Unfortunately, the only way I know of to rename the display name is with the Shell comobject.

```
$shell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
$shell.NameSpace("Z:").Self.Name = "YourNameHere"
```

Comment: Researched this and found the answer!


$Net = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Network  
$Rename = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application  
#### # Map the network drives  
$Net.MapNetworkDrive("L:", '\\SERVER\, USER, PASSWORD)  
#### # Rename everything  
$rename.NameSpace("L:\").Self.Name = 'NAME'


After using the above code it works great, just add more entries for more mapped drives below each of the headings!

Thanks

Comment: @TheRealSlimShady: Please **post your code as an answer** (it's ok to answer your own questions on StackOverflow) and then accept it as answer. | This way, your question will no longer be shown as _unanswered_ and you can use proper formatting, too :)

Comment: This does not seem to be working anymore